QField setting new point from GPS position with distance and bearing
Is it possible, to set a new point from gps position to an other position with distance and bearing? I know, how to calculate x/y with distance/bearing and create a virtual layer with projection of this point. But I won´t place the point where I stand. I will create a point in a distance from my actual position on the fly with QField.
Usage: when I´m in forest and gps signal to a tree is to less, I stand in a free position. I know, I´m 10m/10° away from that tree. I won´t create the point on my local position. The point should be on the tree position.
Now I do this with virtual layer (make_point).
